# Optional Parameter Usage while implementing an interface

Tags: php, interface, laravel

I am making use of the laravel orm component and observed the following when i deployed the life server.

i got the error

```
Declaration of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::toJson() 
must be compatible 
with Illuminate\Support\Contracts\JsonableInterface::toJson($options = 0)
```

I deployed on an ubuntu server that has php v5.4.6 installed. Didnt get this while working on my local machine that has php v5.3.5  installed.

The interface declaration is as below

```
public function toJson($options = 0);
```

while the abstract class implementation is

```
public function toJson()
{
    return json_encode($this->toArray());
}
```

I didnt think this would be a problem since the interface declaration has its parameter as optional and the abstract class implements it without requiring the parameter.

Is this a thing with php v5.4 and what advantage does it offer?

Also, what is the best approach to fixing this? The interface is implemented by a lot of classes so I am trying not to break dependencies; will you advice downgrading my php version on the life server?

Comment: I'd advise actually implementing the optional argument.

Answer (score 5):

In PHP 5.4 a class implementation must match the signature of the abstract or interface.

The interface accepts an argument `$options`, whilst your implementation does not. This is likely causing the error.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php

Just update your toJson() method to accept the `$options` argument.